# scroll in mattable to top

Tags: angular, mat-table

I want to create a button for "move scroll to top" in matTable, but I'm not getting it.

```
<mat-table  #table [dataSource]="dataSource 
   (scroll)="onTableScroll($event)">

      <!--table data -->
</mat-table>

<button (click)="scrollToTop()>Test</button>

//typescript
@ViewChild('table') table: ElementRef;

scrollToTop() {
       this.table.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

but it does not work, nativeElement is not an element of MatTable, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close to the solution, there is just one little thing you are missing. You need to tell `ViewChild` which token you want to read from the selector. In your case that would be `ElementRef`, by passing a second parameter in the form of `{ read: ElementRef }`.

```
@ViewChild('table', {read: ElementRef}) table: ElementRef;
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-gksogt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a stackblitz showing it in action.